# If the standard factorization of an integer n satisfies $p_i\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ for all factors, how to show $n=x^2+y^2$ is solvable with integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is a theorem that if a prime p satisfies $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $p=x^2+y^2$ is solvable.

There is a hint, the identity $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ad+bc)^2+(ac-bd)^2$

By induction on the number of prime factors, it is possible to show that

$n=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2...$ for some number of terms, but how can this be reduced to the required form (two terms)?

Comment: Use the identity to show that $p_1p_2\ldots p_k=x_k^2+y_k^2$.

Comment: How did you arrive at $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+\cdots$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is that $p=x^2+y^2$ is solvable if $p$ is of the form $4k+1$ , which is apparently given.

Induction hypothesis : A product of $n$ prime factors of the form $4k+1$ can be written as $x^2+y^2$

If we have a product of $n+1$ prime factors of the form $4k+1$ , this is a product of $n$ prime factors of the form $4k+1$ and a prime of the form $4k+1$.

The induction hypothesis gives a representation $x^2+y^2 $ for the product with $n$ prime factors and the idendity states that with the factors, a product has such a representation.

Hence you can complete the induction step.